# Scenebuilder/JavaFX polygons mouse event onClick

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, scenebuilder, eclipse-photon

Link to scenebuilder and some Java code: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yBVJQ.jpg

Essentially, navigating and pictures will change based on where the person is going/facing.

I have polygons as D-pad arrows and I want to be able to detect when a person clicks on them. The "up" arrow polygon ID is "forward"
I read that forward.onMouseClickedProperty.addListener() or something can be used, but when I looked up "javafx polygon mouse event" I don't get how to implement into my project.

Can anyone tell me how to set up forward.onMouseClickedProperty.addListener()? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.shape.Polygon;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ClickablePolygonApp extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Polygon polygon = new Polygon();
        polygon.getPoints().addAll(new Double[] {
                0., 80.,
                80., 80.,
                40., 20.
        });

        StackPane stackPane = new StackPane(polygon);
        stackPane.setPrefSize(400., 400.);

        stage.setScene(new Scene(stackPane));
        stage.show();

        polygon.setOnMouseClicked(mouseEvent -> System.out.println("1st way to handle Click!"));
        polygon.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, mouseEvent -> System.out.println("2nd way to handle click!"));
    }
}
```

Comment: How can I tie it to my specific polygon in Scenebuilder if the id is "forward"? Thanks

Comment: `new FXMLLoader(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("yourFxml")).setController(yourControllerClass);`
yourControllerClass should have field `@FXML Polygon forward`. Now it is binded.